# Can Someone Explain "Calling Navigate on Top Level Component" in simple terms

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/

I was reading the documentation in the above link, but i didn't understand "Calling Navigate on Top Level Component" section properly. Can someone explain what this does. I did try to look online but didn't find any resource that explains this in simple terms.

I mainly need help understanding following code :

```
this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', routeName, params });
```

and

```
<AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
```

.

Entire code is given below

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(SomeAppRouteConfigs);

class App extends React.Component {
  someEvent() {
    // call navigate for AppNavigator here:
    this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', routeName, params });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
    );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First. 
AppNavigator is your app router definition .It's look like

```
const AppNavigator=StackNavigator({
    Default:{screen: Page1},
    Favorite:{screen: Page3}
},
{initialRouteName: 'Default'}
)
```

And If you want to set some actions in all pages. Maybe quick link. 
Example Like this
[image]

And in Top Level Component you cannot use "this.props.navigation.navigate()"

Refer : [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)

In order to use navigation at Top Level Component.

you can use "ref" assign a AppNavigator navigator to "Top Level Component" variable.

In this case we define variable is navigator

```
<AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
```

and use below code navigate to your destination

```
this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', routeName:'Favorite', params:'' });
```

Refer : [dispatch](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#dispatch-Send-an-action-to-the-router)